# Как создать массив разных обобщенных типов

Tags: c#

Есть класс Act<T,K>

```
public abstract class Act<T,K>
    {
        public T Input { get; set; }
        public abstract K Action(T input);
    }
```

И к примеру два наследующих его класса

```
public class FindPicA:Act<Bitmap,Point>

public class ClickA : Act<Point, bool>
```

Я не могу понять как хранить их в одном списке
Например, способ ниже(уже проще просто object сделать у переменных) выдает ошибку "Не удается преобразовать из ClickA в Act<object, object>"

```
List<Act<object, object>> acts
```

"Шакалить" все в object не хочется из-за упаковки и распаковки. Можно ли как-то обойти данную проблему?
Сама цель задачи иметь метод Action с разными входными и выходными типами.

Грубо говоря вызов планируется следующим образом, но в данном случае я не вижу возможности уйти от object. Только сейчас увидел, что f не используется, но суть не в этом.

```
public class Actions<T,K> : Act<T, K>
    {
        public List<Act<object, object>> Acts { get; set; }

        public override K Action(T f)
        {
            object prevActRes;
            prevActRes = Input;
            for (int j = 0; j < Acts.Count; j++)
                prevActRes = Acts[j].Action(prevActRes);
            if (prevActRes is K)
                return (K)prevActRes;
            else
                return default(K);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `List<object> acts`. Ну или сделать предка без генериков и тогда `List<BaseAct> acts`.

Comment: А вызывать `Action` как планируете? / Ну, допустим, поместился бы объект в `acts`. Как теперь вызывать `acts[0].Action` - с каким параметром? И какой результат должен получиться?

Comment: Обновил описание, но не знаю на сколько это поможет)

Comment: логика несколько нарушена. `Input` из `Actions` может не подходить к тому, что требует `Acts[j].Action`. В этом случае ты получишь ошибку только в рантайме. Также обрати внимание, что ты не используешь `f` параметр в своем `Action`. Возможно стоит описать проблему которую ты решаешь и найти более подходящее решение

Comment: Да, понимаю. Добавление "Актов" предотвращает такие случаи.

Comment: Возможно стоит описать проблему которую ты решаешь и найти более подходящее решение

Comment: Про _Добавление "Актов" предотвращает такие случаи._ - не понял сообщение

Comment: Не вставлен код тут, но при добавлении в список идет проверка на совместимость типов

Comment: Сама задача требует хранения последовательности действий(без распаковки и упаковки в object), которые можно выполнить в заданном порядке. Действия могут быть разные. Вроде как и все.

Comment: А где у вас упаковка? У вас же классы, а не структуры.

Comment: Пока что в классах FindPicA:Act<Bitmap,Point> и ClickA : Act<Point, bool> я не могу хранить заданные типы и мне придется заменять Bitmap,Point и bool на object и в методе Action приводить их к необходимым мне классам. Также при создании элементов упомянутых ранее классов мне придется упаковывать их в object. Я же хочу избавиться от этого. Ну и уже основной вопрос сейчас возможно ли вообще это?)

Comment: @VladD, Point же структура

Comment: @Grundy: Но в списке должны храниться FindPicA и ClickA.

Comment: @VladD Если я правильно понял, вы подразумеваете хранение списка object, но тогда я не могу вызвать метод Action т.к. не знаю его типа(мб не понимаю как). Так-то можно сделать второй список с типами и по нему вызывать. Не знаю насколько это правильно с точки зрения "чистоты кода". ЗЫ не буду париться и сделаю без обобщенных типов. Звучит не особо ну да лан

Comment: @BrainError тип можно получить вызвав `GetType` - далее простой проверкой.

Comment: @VladD, а ведь не получится же сделать никак кроме `object` чтобы можно было хранить `Action` для цепочки вызовов и типы проверялись? Например, список из функций `[int -> string, string->bool, bool-> int]` - чтобы можно было начать с первой функции, передав ей число, и дальше результат передавать в следующую. То есть по сути Aggregate из LINQ, в котором явно указан тип возвращаемого значения на каждом шаге

Comment: @BrainError: Мне кажется, вы выбрали неправильную структуру данных. Если вам нужно вызывать методы по цепочке, и передавать результат предыдущего метода последующему, то вы должны по идее из `Func<Bitmap, Point>` и `Func<Point, bool>` соорудить сразу `Func<Bitmap, bool>`: `F<T1, T3> Combine<T1, T2, T3>(Func<T1, T2> f, Func<T2, T3> g) => x => g(f(x));`.

Comment: @Grundy: По идее нужно просто скомбинировать функции заранее. Список совершенно ни к чему.

Comment: @VladD, ну не, тогда же, при очень большом количестве функций может стек переполниться  а в цикле - уже нет

Comment: @Grundy: Ээээ... а почему может переполниться вдруг? У нас же при записи `f(g(h(...(x)...)))` нету одновременно выполняющихся функций, каждая функция выполняется строго перед началом выполнения предыдущей.

Comment: @Grundy: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pAHugJ

Comment: @VladD, тут же не `f(g(h(...(x)...)))` получается, когда аргументы вычисляются до передачи в функцию, а по сути запуск одной функции, внутри другой, что и ест стек?

Comment: @Grundy: Хм, да, ну тогда Expression.Compile?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8DSdv2

Comment: @VladD, ага, так больше похоже :)